# How to resize an image i picked from the gallery in android?

Tags: android, image, resize, gallery

I am building an android where. Inside of one activity I have an image button. When I click on it the gallery opens up and I can choose an image. Then I set that image as the new image for the image button.
The problem is the image appears way too big inside my activity. How can I make it fit into my image button?

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

    switch(requestCode) { 
    case SELECT_PHOTO:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();


            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

            mImageButton.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use this method to get a resized image. This way you can avoid OutOfMemoryError

```
public static Bitmap decodeUri(Context c, Uri uri, final int requiredSize) 
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(c.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, o);

        int width_tmp = o.outWidth
                , height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;

        while(true) {
            if(width_tmp / 2 < requiredSize || height_tmp / 2 < requiredSize)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(c.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, o2);
    }
```

---

requiredSize means either one of height or width. Based on this code:

```
if(width_tmp / 2 < requiredSize || height_tmp / 2 < requiredSize)
```

That means, if photo is landscape, 1000x800, and you put required size as 500, then the resulting image will be 500x400. And if the photo is portrait, 800x1000, and requiredSize specified as 500, the resulting image then will be 400x500.

Comment: Can you explain what does `requiredSize` parameter mean?

Comment: Why do you have two `BitmapFactory.Options`?