# How can I set the size of Image when imported in Android?

Tags: android, xml, image, imageview

I am using the following code to let a user import an image from their gallery into the app.

```
 public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
    // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    // Start the Intent
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            // Get the Image from data

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
            imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
```

But, I want the size of the image to be a certain size no matter what the image size they have imported is. Whenever I import an image it always fill the whole screen. Let's say I want the image size to be 50 width by 50 height.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773511/how-to-resize-an-image-i-picked-from-the-gallery-in-android try this

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by saeed:

```
// Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
imgView.setImageBitmap(decodeUri(this, Uri.parse(imgDecodableString), 50));
```

Where `decodeUri` is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773511/how-to-resize-an-image-i-picked-from-the-gallery-in-android?answertab=oldest#tab-top).